# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.for /register

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to POST form data using ajax:

```
var data = $('#form1').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/register',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(typeof(data));
}});
```

but I get :

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

but, the web.php have the:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

I tried to add the following route before the Auth::routes(['verify' => true]) :

```
Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register');
```

also tried clearing route cache but none of them worked.

Note: I use the similar ajax to post login data with no problem it is only with /register

what is the problem? how to fix it? please help

**Update**

I have tried the default register blade and it works so I think this problem have to do with Ajax specifically, but, I do not know why yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any weird things on your code.

I think your error can be occurred by routing cache.

How about input this command?

```
$ php artisan route:cache
```

### Added

I tested this code and it works.

**Remove route cache file**

```
$ php artisan route:clear
```

**In View**

```
<form id="form1">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="test" value="">
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**In JS**

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#form1').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '/register',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```

**In web.php**

```php
<?php
Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register');
```

**In RegisterController.php**

```php
<?php
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register()
    {
        return request();
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Comment: There is sample code in `routes/api.php` file. So if you didn't have route of `api/users`, error is occurred. Above the **LogicException**, you might be able to see the `Route cache cleared!` message. If you can see that message, clearing route is succeess. By the way, error is occurred yet?

Comment: I committed everything in api.php and then re-issued the command php artisan route:cache and it was executed successfully but the main error persists.

Comment: I added some codes and that works for me. I used your ajax code, and it works. so it's not ajax problem probably.

Comment: Cool. I think it has been occurred by route cache, maybe. Have a good day!